# Akka Test not triggered by Maven Scalatest plugin

Tags: maven, akka, akka-http, akka-testkit, scalatest-maven-plugin

The unit tests of my Akka & Akka Http applicaton cannot be triggered when doing "mvn test".

I found a similar question on [Scalatest Maven Plugin "no tests were executed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38700319/scalatest-maven-plugin-no-tests-were-executed) , and tried the solution mentioned there, but no luck for me.

The project config:
Java: 1.8
Scala: 2.11.8
Akka: 2.4.17
Akka http: 10.0.3
scalatest: 3.0.1
mvn:3.3.9

The pom.xml :

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
                <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                    <!-- <junitxml>.</junitxml>
                    <filereports>WDF TestSuite.txt</filereports> -->
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```